# eclipse IDE after a brand new install not start but complains

Tags: java, eclipse

Premise:
I am constrained to work on a very old Ubuntu 10.04LTS(aka Lucid Lynx) 
After have downloaded (now) Oracle's most used 1.8 Java(and latest 1.8 release: 1.8.0_172) decompressed it and set it correctly in PATH in bash i downloaded and decompressed in $ECLIPSE_HOME the latest runnable(cause eclipse releases >= Oxygen require a newer gtk library that actually can't have in that PC) eclipse for my machine: eclipse-java-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz 
When i tried to execute eclipse instead of a running instance i got that error dialog message

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so
-startup /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 6e8037
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJavaNeon64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
```

Anyone has a clue? 
TIA

Best Regards 
Harry G.T. Kar

Comment: Eclipse Neon requires Java 8, but according to Oracle https://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml, Ubuntu 10.04 is not listed as a certified platform for Java 8 (it is for Java 7). Is Java 8 otherwise working? e.g does a simple program compile and run from the command line? If so that would narrow it down to being an Eclipse specific problem.

Comment: "Oxygen require a newer gtk library" eclipse uses native code, and requires a more recent gtk/gnome to function. You could try Netbeans.

Comment: *"I am constrained to work on a very old Ubuntu 10.04 LTS"* - That is your problem!  10.0.4 LTS is 8 years old and passed end-of-life > 3 years ago.  Getting new Java / new IDE etc working on an ancient OS platform will be a world of pain.  Your best solution is to upgrade / replace the OS.  Buy a new computer if you need to.

Comment: @ paisanco: Confirm that Java itself works flawlessly for simple and complex programs as it does the problem is definitely from eclipse  side smell to me as something trivial is missing but what ?

Comment: @  Elliott Frisch : if i can't resolve about eclipse that's the next option

Comment: @  Stephen C: obvious but a new machine is out of view for now apart of that the system works as intended except little annoyances like that one derived maybe from the fact i can't have the latest  packages software releases. Anyway here we are

Comment: For completeness system's default java release was :
java version "1.6.0_35"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.7) (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
<br\>
the actual is: 
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: forgot to thank all you for your responses

Answer (score 0):

All that time i was focused to search in Web for a solution (but without luck) and not dig into the eclipse.ini file assumed it correct.
My eclipse.ini after eclipse installation looked like that:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

I notice here missed the path to java(JDK) actually in use(don't forget i used a custom installation of java - in my home directory - not that provided from the Ubuntu system in /usr/bin/ as the error message correctly reported)
So the solution was simply to add 2 lines in the eclipse.ini(i.e. the custom path to JDK).

**Beware it's important to write these lines before the -vmargs as shown below (or also delete -vmargs if not use it)**

```
 -vm
/home/harrykar/Java8/jdk1.8.0_172/bin
-vmargs
```

And that's it eclipse now works as intended

Best Regards

Harry G.T. Kar