# After an abrupt PC's restart eclipse not start and emit: VM terminated. Exit code=1

Tags: eclipse, crash, ide

Eclipse IDE was open during an electric energy blackout. On machine's restart eclipse not run normally instead complains(crash) with an error dialog box:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/jre/bin/java
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so
-startup /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 380035
-vm /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
```

Comment: How about upgrading to a current version instead of restoring an outdated version? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: @howlger Simply because for some reason/constrains not all of us can have available the latest release e.g. what you can do if your boss assign you an old machine?(see link in the answer)

Comment: Especially if you have an old machine, I would recommend the current Eclipse version (and OpenJ9 as Java VM) for performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah i know usually  "newer is better" but if Eclipse Oxygen require a newer() version of gtk libraries to work with i guess the actual Eclipse have the same requirement too and i haven't the responsibility to  change operating system myself. 
Anyway the installed Eclipse Neon haven't observable drawbacks till now. About OpenJ9 you know if can run with Neon?

Comment: I didn't try it out, but OpenJ9 with OpenJDK 8 should also work with Neon: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=openj9 ([but you have to copy the missing certificate authority (CA) certificates from OpenJDK 10](https://eclipsehowl.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/hello-openj9-on-windows-i-didnt-expect-you-so-soon/))

Comment: Thank you for the info's. I took a very first tour on OpenJ9 but from https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/openj9_support/ evince "Note: Not all of these distributions are tested, but Linux distributions that have a minimum glibc version 2.12 are expected to function without problems." in my old machine is available   glibc version 2.11.1 i doubt OpenJ9 will work but when i find time i do a try

Answer (score 0):

I had see the *"JVM terminated. Exit code=1"* for an unrelated problem([eclipse IDE after a brand new install not start but complains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803854/eclipse-ide-after-a-brand-new-install-not-start-but-complains/51807375#51807375)) someday ago

So the first thing i did was to control the content of the eclipse.ini file in $ECLIPSE_HOME. Strangely enough eclipse.ini resulted  empty(probably from the blackout)so i did a brand new copy in $ECLIPSE_HOME of the original eclipse.ini from the installation package .tar.gz fortunately still i took apart.

On the next eclipse's start eclipse still complained with:

```
 JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so
-startup /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 350035
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/harrykar/Java8/eclipseJava//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
```

Ok i forgot to put the JDK path in eclipse.ini

**Beware it's important to write these lines before the -vmargs as shown below**

```
 -vm
/home/harrykar/Java8/jdk1.8.0_172/bin
-vmargs
```

After that addition eclipse.ini now looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/home/harrykar/Java8/jdk1.8.0_172/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Finally now Eclipse works as intended

Best Regards

Harry G.T. Kar